# Setting persistence and vim's DoMatchParen

Tags: linux, macos, vim

I was playing around with parentheses highlighting in vim. Entering `:DoMatchParen` into the vim command buffer does exactly what I want, but I was wondering if anyone knows exactly how this setting is "saved."

If I type `:syntax on` into vim, exit and reopen vim, the syntax coloring is gone as expected. The `:DoMatchParen` setting persists through closing vim, and I've tested this with no `~/.vimrc` and nothing in my `~/.vim/`directory.

From some Googling, it looks like `:DoMatchParen` enables a plugin to highlight matching parentheses (and you can type `:NoMatchParen` to disable it), but I still don't understand how this setting persists exactly. The setting doesn't appear to be stored in `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/`. I looked at `/usr/share/vim` (there's a vimrc file there as well as a plugin folder inside `/usr/share/vim/vim80/`) but this appears to be a "global install" directory for vim that's not modified.

I am using macOS if that makes a difference.

Edit: I realize I may not have done the best job explaining my question. I have no problems with getting vim configured the way I want. I'm just curious as to how `:DoMatchParen` "remembers" its setting (highlight matching parentheses is turned on). I can put this in my .vimrc, but it turns out I don't even need to. If I type `:DoMatchParen` once, the setting is permanently saved. How does this happen?

Thanks!

LAST EDIT: Well, I feel really silly. It turns out parentheses highlighting is on by default, just like Bo said (in the comments below). For some reason I thought I had turned it on, but it must've been on by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.vimrc` is the place to put this sort of configuration if you want it to persist between sessions.

You can include it just as you would type it for your current session. You can add a comment about what it does with a line that starts with `"`.

`" Highlight the matching parenthesis or brace.
:DoMatchParen`

Comment: I appreciate the response! 

I realize I may not have done the best job explaining my question. I have no problems with getting vim configured the way I want. I'm just curious as to how `:DoMatchParen` "remembers" its setting (highlight matching parentheses is turned on). I can put this in my .vimrc, but it turns out I don't even need to. If I type `:DoMatchParen` once, the setting is permanently saved. How does this happen?

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood. As far as I know `:DoMatchParen` is enabled by default these days. It is a [standard plugin](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_paren.html). Have you tried setting `:NoMatchParen` to see if it also automatically persists across sessions?

Comment: Well, I feel *really* silly. I tried that, and `:NoMatchParen` does not persist across sessions. I hopped on to another computer (that has never run vim before) and it turns out parentheses highlighting is on by default, just like you said. For some reason I thought I had turned it on, but it must've been on by default. No wonder it was "persisting" for me! Thanks for your help Bo!